# regexp_substr in sql to separate numbers from text field

Tags: regexp-substr

I have a sql that returns comments based on employee feedback.

As you can see with the comments below, the formatting can be a bit different.

Is there a way that i can extract the numbers out?

Examples :

```
W.C. 06.07.2022 change from 7 to 5
wk com 13/07 demand 8 change to 13
Increase demand from 7 to 12 W/C 11/07
```

Output Result

```
7 and 5, 
8 and 13, 
7 and 12
```

Comment: What is your actual SQL database (e.g. Oracle, Postgres, MySQL, etc.) ?  We need to know this in order to give you an answer.

Comment: Hi Tim. Apologies. Forgot to add it. I’m using oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way given the sample data.  First identify the group of 1 or more numbers followed by an optional group of the word of "change" and a space, followed by the word "to and a space, then 1 or more digits.  Within that group, group the digits desired.  Of course, big assumptions here on the words between the numbers.

```
WITH tbl(ID, emp_comment) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'W.C. 06.07.2022 change from 7 to 5' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'wk com 13/07 demand 8 change to 13' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Increase demand from 7 to 12 W/C 11/07' FROM dual
)
SELECT ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR(emp_comment, '.* ((\d+) (change )?to \d+).*', 1, 1, NULL, 2) nbr_1,
 REGEXP_SUBSTR(emp_comment, '.* (\d+ (change )?to (\d+)).*', 1, 1, NULL, 3) nbr_2
FROM tbl;

        ID NBR_1 NBR_2
---------- ----- -----
         1 7     5    
         2 8     13   
         3 7     12   

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: Hi Gary, thank you so much for this. This is absolutely what I'm looking for. Is there a way where I can shout you a coffee or something for this?

Comment: @JonathonChau Just the fact that you want to do that is thanks enough!  Happy to help.  Oh and mark the answer as accepted to show future searchers it helped you :-)

Comment: Hi Gary, just accepted it. Cheers.